# cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

Any idea why am I getting this error? I thought `List` implements `IEnumerable`.

```
        var customization = new List<CustomerOrderCustomizationDTO>();

        customization.Add(new CustomerOrderCustomizationDTO()
        {
            ProductCustomizationID = _uow.Product.GetCustomization("LENGTH").ID,
            Value = length.ToString()
        });

        customization.Add(new CustomerOrderCustomizationDTO()
        {
            ProductCustomizationID = _uow.Product.GetCustomization("WIDTH").ID,
            Value = width.ToString()
        });

        customization.Add(new CustomerOrderCustomizationDTO()
        {
            ProductCustomizationID = _uow.Product.GetCustomization("WEIGHT").ID,
            Value = weight.ToString()
        });

        return _uow.Product.GetProductPrice(productID, ref customization); //ERROR
```

Interface

```
decimal GetProductPrice(int productID, ref IEnumerable<CustomerOrderCustomizationDTO> custOrderCustomizations);
```

Comment: Would you please share the error you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `custOrderCustomizations` is a `ref` parameter, that means that the parameter type (`IEnumerable`) must be assignable to the type of the variable that you pass in. In this case, you are passing in the `customization` variable, which is a `List`. You can't assign an `IEnumerable` to a `List`.

One solution would be to assign your `customization` variable to a new variable of type `IEnumerable` and pass that to `GetProductPrice`, like so:

```
IEnumerable<CustomerOrderCustomizationDTO> tempCustomizations = customization;
return _uow.Product.GetProductPrice(productID, ref tempCustomizations);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `ref` it is sort of like a pointer in c++.  That being said, the types have to match, not be heritable.  You will need to cast `customization` to `IEnumerable<CustomerOrderCustomizationDTO>` in order to pass it by `ref`. You can read more about the `ref` keyword [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref).

You might be able to get away with removing `ref` since `List<>` is a reference type and is not passed by value like `int` for example.  Then you would not have to cast.